# Necessary moment condition for the law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be iid random variables, and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$, $n \geq 1$. It seems
classical that if
$$
    \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac {|S_n|}{\sqrt {2 n \ln \ln n}} < \infty
$$
almost surely, then $E(X_1^2) < \infty$ (and $E(X_1) = 0$). But what is a proof of this result?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

This is a theorem due to [Strassen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00539114), whose proof is based on Skorokhod's representation of zero-mean distributions on $\mathbb R$ by means of the Brownian motion.

[Heyde](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212088) gave a direct proof of this result, without using Skorokhod's representation.

This result is cited e.g. in  Supplement 1 in Section 4 of Chapter X of the book by [Petrov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9).